# Order of hooks during Drupal 7 install

Tags: drupal-7, hook

I'd like to know in what order following hooks called:

hook_install
hook_enable
any other hooks

Basically What I'd like to know is if any hooks in my .module file are called before calling hook_enable.

In other words what is the order of calling hooks:
A: install, any, enable
B: install, enable, any

Some reference would be appreciated ( i haven't found any).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some useful info on extracting the hook calls here: https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/drupal-exposed

This one will probably help you:
Open includes/module.inc and find the module_implements function.
Add the following line:

```
drupal_set_message("hook_$hook");
```

This should give you a list of hooks as they are called.
Presumably, if you install a module you should see the install hooks in action.